# Group json object by keys postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

So I have a table called `data` which have 4 columns name (string), value (string), created_at (timestamp), r_id (int8) and I'm trying to get a JSON object which give me all the values grouped by a concat of the name and r_id. The closest I've achieved is as following:

```
SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), json_build_array("data".value,created_at))
FROM data
```

Gives:

```
{"Name1" : ["69.39", "2018-02-19T16:27:17.482111"]}
{"Name1" : ["69.66", "2018-02-19T16:26:21.075247"]}
{"Name1" : ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:28.809292"]}
{"NewName1" : ["25.75", "2018-02-19T16:27:29.024595"]}
...
```

Expected:

```
{"Name1" : [["69.39", "2018-02-19T16:27:17.482111"],["69.66", "2018-02-19T16:26:21.075247"],["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:28.809292"]]}
{"NewName1" : [["25.75", "2018-02-19T16:27:29.024595"]]}
...
```

Comment: try `SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), json_agg(json_build_array("data".value,created_at)))
FROM data group by concat(name, r_id)`

Comment: It worked Great! I just also need to order it by created_at. If I try to add `ORDER BY created_at ASC` It messes up again :\

Comment: this worked `SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), json_agg(json_build_array(value,created_at) ORDER BY created_at ASC))
FROM data
group by concat(name, r_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `json_agg` to aggregate arrays over:

```
SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), json_agg(json_build_array("data".value,created_at))) 
FROM data group by concat(name, r_id)
```

of course if you need it ordered you can add order:

```
SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), json_agg(json_build_array(value,created_at) ORDER BY created_at ASC))
FROM data
group by concat(name, r_id)
```